# findViewById sometimes returns null in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

findViewById is returning null when searching for an ImageView inside a fragment, but not for a TextView.

Here is my code:

fragment.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.herecomesthefragmentname">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/card_1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txt_1"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/2_card"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/mr_layout">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/2_imag"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_1"
                    android:scaleType="fitStart"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txt_2"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large.Inverse"
                     />

            </RelativeLayout>

          </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
      </LinearLayout>
    <!-- here goes another cardview -->
  </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment.java (not all):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Get Views

    txt_container = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_2);
    img_view = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.2_imag);
}
```

The strange thing is that the `txt_2` view is found but not the `2_imag` one.

I have tried renaming it, but it does nothing. Also, I have notice that i can't find the RelativeLayout and CardView containig both either.

UPDATE: It seems that I can't find even the main CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, a fragment-v21.xml file was being loaded instead of fragment.xml.

The v21 one had different code.